# Kaustic Machine's Atari Punk Console: Line Output or Log Pot?

Tags: audio, 555

I'm planning to make a atari punk console for an electronics project,  but i have a question, the original circuit published here: http://compiler.kaustic.net/machines/apc.html has a "line outout". Is this a suitable way to drive headphones as well? Should i remove this resistor array and replace it with a log pot in series with the 556's output? Or how should I modify the circuit to drive headphones and have some kind of volume control?

Also, is line output that important?

Answer (score 2):

In order to drive a speaker (or headphones) you need to supply quite a bit of current, and the 556 can't do that. If the speaker has its own amplifier - for example, USB or portable speakers - you may be able to connect this circuit directly. That said, headphones are usually not amplified, so you will need to amplify the signal yourself with an op-amp. The typical application circuit for a LM386 will probably accomplish what you need. Just connect your line out to Vin. It even has a 10k potentiometer for volume control! Just be sure to use a logarithmic pot for best results.

[image: Typical LM386 Application]

Comment: The 556 *will* drive an 8ohm speaker, which is exactly how the original circuit is designed: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FFmeyiEPEJs/VKCQ81DEjYI/AAAAAAAABn8/OyUX9ZcMDOk/s1600/stepped-tone-generator.png